# formdata is not reaching the backend

Tags: node.js, angular, nestjs

I am submitting an html form in my application, am getting the submitted data in console before sending the http request from angular front end but the data is not reaching the backend in NodeJS. The code is working when i submit form from postman.

```
 <form [formGroup] = "myform" (ngSubmit) = "myFormSubmit()">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
 <div *ngFor="let data of dataArr;index as i>
 <input type="checkbox" id="1" [value]="data.id" name="{{ data.id }}" 
 (change)="getSelectedData($event)" formArrayName="checkboxData">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" [disabled] = "!myform.valid">Save</button>
 </form>

 myFormSubmit() {
   console.log(this.myform.value); // i can see all submitted form values here
   this.service.postmyForm(this.myform.value).subscribe(response =>{
 });
 }

 private headerData = {
 headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Content-Length': '541385555',
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
})
};

public postmyForm(formData): Observable<any> {
  console.log('formData'+ JSON.stringify(formData)); //i can see submitted data in console
  return this.http.post(this.url+ '/adduser', { formData }, this.headerData);
}

Nodejs Backend:-  
 @Post('/adduser')
  adduser(@Request() req) {
    console.log(req.body.name);return;  //Am not getting the form value here
  }
```

Comment: When you use Postman to send the data it works? Also, check `req.body` your form might be coming with `formData` key when you send it using Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
return this.http.post(this.url+ '/adduser', formData, this.headerData);
```

without `{ }` around formData

Reason is as you have passed it with `{ }` the body that you send will be

```
 { 
   "formData": {
              name: "something",
              ....
            }
          }
```

while you try to access it directly with name here `console.log(req.body.name)` where with your version it should be `console.log(req.body.formData.name)`

But if you remove `{ }` it could be accessible with  `console.log(req.body.name)` as the object will be passed in the following form

```
 { 
    "name": "something",
    ...
  }
```

Comment: oh! Thank you so much for the help! sad that i couldn't figure it out i should use some debugger i think!

Comment: but i wonder in backend i couldnot even console req,req.body.formData, req.body.formData.name!